# What are the dimensions of the generic quadrotor in the hector quadrotor package?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, collada-urdf, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

The description page (http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor_description) talks about quadrotor_hokuyo_utm30lx.urdf.xacro providing the description but I am a little bit confused reading the file, where specifically or under which tag do I find the dimensions. By dimensions I mean the height, rotor radius, weight, max distance from the center etc.

Adi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301599/what-are-the-dimensions-of-the-generic-quadrotor-in-the-hector-quadrotor-package?/) by [fabritya](https://answers.ros.org/users/36392/fabritya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Geometry is defined by the meshes in the [hector_quadrotor_description/meshes/quadrotor](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/tree/kinetic-devel/hector_quadrotor_description/meshes/quadrotor) folder. The blender, .stl and .dae files all contain the same geometry, just in different formats. Easiest option to look at is probably the .stl file, this can be opened/imported with many tools. You can even view it [online on github](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/blob/kinetic-devel/hector_quadrotor_description/meshes/quadrotor/quadrotor_base.stl).

Inertial parameters are defined via the respective tags in the URDF/xacro files. For the basic quadrotor you can look [at line 11 in quadrotor_base.urdf.xacro](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/blob/kinetic-devel/hector_quadrotor_description/urdf/quadrotor_base.urdf.xacro#L11).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2018-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabritya](https://answers.ros.org/users/36392/fabritya/) on 2018-08-26**:
Thank you Stefan for your quick response. I think I got the values I needed. One final question: Are all the units in SI units?  So those values would be (kg*m^2)